# Stuck - Joining 3 tables, performing function on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Forgive me as newbie. I have a multi-level join table around the following...

```
Category
has_many :products

Products
has_many :sales

Sales
belongs_to :product
```

Within the category I am looking to display a list of each of the best-selling products (as determined by the number of sales, which are individually logged).

I can print a total sum of sale value on the product page OK (which is column sales.sum - my column is called sum), but cannot print a full list of all products fitting into a category, whilst performing a sum function on the sales.sum column for each product.

I currently have this code in category controller;

```
 def show
    @all = Category.joins(products: :sales)
 end
```

I think this is right but I cannot get the right view. Appreciate this may not be the best way to present the question on SO, but tried many different ways to print it in my view file, but really stuck.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance! :-)

EDIT - to make it a bit clearer what I'm trying to achieve...

**Category -> Products -> Sales**

Want to display a list of each Product that belongs to a `Category` (by `category_id`), but put them in list of total `Sales` (which belongs to Products by `product_id`. Column is called `'sum'` within the `Sales` table and shows value such as $100 Product 1, $50 Product 2, $40 Product 1, et cetera).

So, multi level join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, finally worked out the answer;

```
<ol>
    <%= @category.products.each do |su| %>
    <li><%= su.name %> <%= su.sales.sum(:sum) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

Hope this helps someone else!